# Resonance peak occuring in Bode plot of DC-DC Control Loop before the cross over frequency. Why?

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, control

[image]

Like, how does the resonance happen before the cross over frequency? Can someone explain the intuition behind it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance

Comment: LC resonance? Is the LC Filter at the Output of a Buck DC-DC , a low pass filter?

Comment: Like, how does the resonance happen before the cross over frequency? Can someone explain the intuition behind it?

Comment: It indicates a high impedance resonant output causing gain.

Comment: How does it occur before the cross over frequency

Comment: The schematic would explain that

Comment: The schematic is a DC-DC Buck Converter.

Comment: Please add the schematic and all relevant assumptions to your post.

Comment: Looks pretty normal to me but, you should be clear about the circuit.

Comment: You would need to plot the power stage response first then that of the compensator. This curve looks strange and perhaps it is not the compensated loop gain? How did you obtain it, from a Laplace expression? What is the switching frequency of this converter?

Answer (score 1):

Because of parasitics usually or from actual components. It's hard to say what it's coming from but the list includes the ESR of the inductor and capacitors or even compensation on the feedback loop. It occurs before the cross over frequency because any physical poles will create a pole that factors into the control loop.

In the case of a buck DC DC controller, it's the output filter that does (the paper shows the transfer function and the output response):

[image]
Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/238517757_Digitally-controlled_high-frequency_DC-DC_buck_converter